# How to check the ability to serialize a json to a concrete object?

Tags: java, json

How to check the ability to serialize a json to a concrete object?

```
ObjectNode orderNode = objectNode.with(ORDER_NODE);
        Payment paymentOrderDto = objectMapper.readValue(orderNode.toString(), Payment.class);
```

But this json can not be only Payment, it can also be another object. For example User 
And I need to understand, depending on the content of json, which object I will use
Payment: `objectMapper.readValue(orderNode.toString(), Payment.class);`

Or User: `objectMapper.readValue(orderNode.toString(), User.class);`

Comment: Please add more information: Which lib are you using? Please add complete code sample and make more clear what is the very concrete problem.

Comment: you could check `objectNode.fieldNames()`... if `firstname` is present map it to `User` if not map it to `Payment` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use genecric method.

```
<T> T fromNodeToObject(ObjectNode objectNode, Class<T> tClass) throws Exception{
    return new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(objectNode, tClass);
}
```

then convert like this:

```
Payment paymentOrderDto = fromNodeToObject(objectNode,Payment.class);
```

Comment: for me this decision does not fit. I need to understand exactly on the basis of json what this object is. Initially, I do not know what exactly the object came to me.

Comment: It would be nice to use something like instanceof

Comment: This is a professional Q&A site, do not use text speak.